# Django ORM equivalent for this SQL: ORDER BY CONVERT(...)

Tags: django, orm

My SQL query's like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_model ORDER BY CONVERT(my_field USING tis620)
```

I've also tried with this (it's surely wrong):

```
MyModel.objects.extra(order_by=['CONVERT(my_field USING tis620) ASC'])
```

Is there a django orm equivalent for this kind of "ORDER BY" SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'converted': 'CONVERT(my_field USING tis620)'},
    order_by=['converted'])
```